# mysql INT(11) error

Tags: mysql, linux, terminal

I am trying to create a table and I thought everything looked good but this error keeps coming up.

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(11) NOT NULL,
 menu_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
 position INT(3) NOT NULL,
 visi' at line 3

Here is the command I entered in the terminal:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE pages (
-> ID INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
->  subject_id(11) NOT NULL,
->  menu_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
->  position INT(3) NOT NULL,
->  visible TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
->  context TEXT,
->  PRIMARY KEY (id),
->  INDEX (subject_id)
-> );
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Normally `INT` is sufficient, just leave it with the defaults. Unless you're out to shave every byte off your record size the difference will be imperceptible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem near < subject_id >

```
 CREATE TABLE pages (
    -> ID INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->  subject_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
    ->  menu_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    ->  position INT(3) NOT NULL,
    ->  visible TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
    ->  context TEXT,
    ->  PRIMARY KEY (id),
    ->  INDEX (subject_id)
    -> );
```